# Not able to send mail using sendGrid API

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendgrid

```
$sendgrid = new SendGrid($sendgrid_username, $sendgrid_password, array("turn_off_ssl_verification" => true));
    $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
    // $email    = new SendGrid\Email();
    $email->addTo($to)->
    setfrom("info.kickingworld@gmail.com")->
    setFromName("Kicking World")->
    addSubstitution("[%first_name | Customer%]", array($fist_name))->
    addSubstitution("[%first_name | Default Value%]", array($last_name))->
    addSubstitution("[Sender_Name]", array("Kicking World"))->
    addSubstitution("[Sender_Address]", array())->
    addSubstitution("[Sender_City]", array())->
    addSubstitution("[Sender_State]", array())->
    addSubstitution("[Sender_Zip]", array())->
    addSubstitution("<%asm_group_unsubscribe_raw_url%>", array())->
    addSubstitution("[Weblink]", array())->
    addHeader('X-Sent-Using', 'SendGrid-API')->
    addHeader('X-Transport', 'web')->
    setSubject('cancelation')->
    setHTML('Body')->
    setTemplateId($template);
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
```

I am trying to send mail using sendgrid mail API using PHP but i am getting error.

```
Message: Call to a member function setfrom() on null
```

i am new here and this is my first post. need help!

Comment: It would seem that the `addTo()` method does not return the object. So instead of chaining all calls using `->` you probably have to use `$email->...();` everywhere (where `...` is the method you want to call).

Comment: Yep, have a look at the https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/USE_CASES.md#send-an-email-to-multiple-recipients. They have a whole load of samples.